# How to reach subdomains on DNS name of a Public IP Address created on Azure?

Tags: azure, dns, ip, wildcard-subdomain

I created a **Public IP Address** on Azure and assigned a **DNS name** like `contoso.eastus2.cloudapp.azure.com`.

When I use a DNS lookup with this DNS name, an `A` record is found to point on my Public IP address. But when I try to lookup a subdomain (like `foo.contoso.eastus2.cloudapp.azure.com`), no records are found.

How to configure the Public IP Address for subdomains (`*.contoso.eastus2.cloudapp.azure.com`) point at same IP address than the parent domain ?

Answer (score 1):

Azure only provide such as `location.cloudapp.azure.com` (where location is the location you select) to the name you provide to create the fully qualified DNS name. You just can inject single label to that DNS suffix and can't add multiple labels.

Instead of using the DNS name label with the default suffix, you can use the Azure DNS service or your own DNS service to configure a DNS name with a custom suffix that resolves to the public IP address. For more information, see [Use Azure DNS with an Azure public IP address](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dns/dns-custom-domain?toc=/azure/virtual-network/toc.json#public-ip-address).

Comment: I don't have the ability to manage a DNS zone on a custom domain. Thanks for your answer

Comment: What's your read purpose? Do you want to use the DNS name privately?

Comment: No, It's an issue because not being alined with the  company strategy. They don't want to provide us a custom domain. But we need to host a public k8s cluster on Azure.

Comment: Currently, you have nothing to do with the default Azure provided DNS name unless you use a custom domain.